# Rust difference between [fn] vs [(fn, u8)]

Tags: rust, type-inference

Why does this compile:

```
fn main() {
   let xs = [||1, ||2, ||3];
}
```

but [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dce79095ad1162a60dd65d0937c49bba) does not?

```
fn main() {
   let xs = [(||1, 1), (||2, 2), (||3, 3)] ;
}
```

EDIT: To be clear, the question is not *why does it not compile*. It is *what is the difference between these two that makes the first compile but the second does not?*.

Comment: Because (straight from the compiler) "no two closures, even if identical, have the same type"

Comment: @MindSwipe Then why does the first compile?

Comment: I dont really get it either, but seems like the compiler is infering the type to be something else than in the first example. Giving it an explicit type of `[(fn() -> u8, u8);3]` makes it compile.

Comment: It is indicated by RA that in the first one the type has been coerced to `fn() -> i32` and thus is no longer `|| -> i32`.

Comment: I would also recommend you to file issue/bug in Rust repository

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first case is special cased in the compiler: when some types are required to unify (such as when all of them are elements of the same array), and all of them are non-capturing closures, the compiler automatically coerces them to function pointers. This does not work if they are tuple that contain non-capturing closures, however.

[The relevant code in rustc is here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d7dd01fe8b071602510eaac9f676acc0e3cf8e4a/compiler/rustc_hir_analysis/src/check/coercion.rs#L1116-L1210), if you're interested.